# Clean way to lazy initialize and cache internal value in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

Let the code speak for itself first with naive approach:

```
int heavy_calc() // needed to be called once
{
    // sleep(7500000 years)
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = [] {
        // And cached for lambda return value
        static int cache = heavy_calc();
        return cache;
    };
    return foo() + foo();
}
```

I want to have lambda internal cached value calculated on the first call. An naive approach is to use `static` cache, but it [increases binary size and refuses to be be inlined](https://godbolt.org/z/0kQN_e).

I came up with creating `cache` in capture list and marking lambda as `mutable`, what [inlines without problems](https://godbolt.org/z/K37Psw), but requires cache to start with default value, which may break class invariant.

```
auto foo = [cache=0] () mutable {
    // And cached for lambda return value
    if(!cache)
        cache = heavy_calc();
    return cache;
};
```

My third approach uses [`boost::optional` in mutable `lambda`](https://godbolt.org/z/mTpZvT)

```
auto foo = [cache=std::optional<int>{}] () mutable {
    // And cached for lambda return value
    if(!cache)
        cache = heavy_calc();
    return *cache;
};
```

It works properly, but looks for me as kind of capture list + `mutable` keyword hack. Also `mutable` affects all captured parameters, so makes lambda less safe in real use.

Maybe there is an better/more clean solution for this? Or just different approach which ends up with the very same effect.

EDIT, some background:
Lambda approach is chosen as I am modifying some callback lambda, which currently is used as:
`[this, param]{this->onEvent(heavy_calc(param));}`
I want to reduce `heavy_calc` calls without evaluating it in advance (only on first call)

Comment: heavy_calc should be called once inside the lambda or can it be called outside? ( the question is asked for thread safety reasons )

Comment: I'd love to call it only inside. I didn't take thread safety into account, but another naive solution with thread safety would be `thread_local` instead of `static`, right?

Comment: your answer with static is ok from a thread safety perspective. In C++11 from what I know you are guaranteed thread safe initialization of the static variable. Another option would be using call_once https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once but I would go with static.

Comment: So both thread_local and static are ok. My question about thread safety was related to on what thread should heavy_calc be called. And you answered that it should be called from the thread that is calling the first lambda function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I don't see any reason to use lambda here. You can write a regular reusable class to cache calculation value. If you insist on using lambda then you can move value calculation to parameters so there will be no need to make anything `mutable`:

```
int heavy_calc() // needed to be called once
{
    // sleep(7500000 years)
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    auto foo
    {
        [cache = heavy_calc()](void)
        {
            return cache;
        }
    };
    return foo() + foo();
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JAwXoHBU3qm877z8)

With a bit of template it is possible to write a class that will lazy evaluate and cache result of arbitrary calculation:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <utility>

template<typename x_Action> class
t_LazyCached final
{
    private: x_Action m_action;
    private: ::boost::optional<decltype(::std::declval<x_Action>()())> m_cache;

    public: template<typename xx_Action> explicit
    t_LazyCached(xx_Action && action): m_action{::std::forward<xx_Action>(action)}, m_cache{} {}

    public: auto const &
    operator ()(void)
    {
        if(not m_cache)
        {
            m_cache = m_action();
        }
        return m_cache.value();
    }
};

template<typename x_Action> auto
Make_LazyCached(x_Action && action)
{
    return t_LazyCached<x_Action>{::std::forward<x_Action>(action)};
}

class t_Obj
{
    public: int heavy_calc(int param) // needed to be called once
    {
        // sleep(7500000 years)
        return 42 + param;
    }
};

int main()
{
    t_Obj obj{};
    int param{3};
    auto foo{Make_LazyCached([&](void){ return obj.heavy_calc(param); })};
    return foo() + foo();
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uIen3t2gs5jXgcRj)

Comment: I think the idea is to not call `heavy_calc()` if not needed, e.g., if you have some branches that may not use `foo`. Otherwise I completely agree about the reusable cache class.

Comment: When is `cache = heavy_calc()` actually executed in this case?

Comment: @GPhilo When lambda is constructed

Comment: I've simplified the case here, I am modyfing exising callback lambda which basically currently does: `[this,param]{this->call(heavy_calc(param));}`

Comment: @R2RT So is your primary target to achieve lazy evaluation? This matter would be somewhat different from just caching (though regular reusable class would work as well).

Comment: Yes, I meant it in first sentence "calculated on the first call". I've added an edit to make it more explicit in question.

Comment: @VTT So in your `return` you'd call `heavy_calc` twice because of the double `foo`? Or is the lambda constructed only once when `foo` is defined and then called implicitly by `foo`'s `operator()`? (Also, what is `foo` exactly? A nameless class? Some kind of function? I've never come up such a use of `auto` before)

Comment: @GPhilo `foo` is a instance of anonymous callable class,  `heavy_calc` will be invoked only once when `foo` is constructed.

Comment: @VTT thanks for the clarification, would you maybe also know where to get more information about anonymous callable classes? (Googling "anonymous callable class c++" and "callable class c++" didn't seem to return anything similar, but maybe I'm just missing something)

Comment: @papagaga I'm familiar with lambdas, what's confusing to me is the construct `auto name {lambda_def};`. Would this be equivalent to `auto foo = lambda_def;`?

Comment: @GPhilo: then you need to take a look at brace initialization

Answer (score 2):

> It works properly, but looks for me as kind of capture list + mutable keyword hack. Also mutable affects all captured parameters, so makes lambda less safe in real use.

There is the solution to roll your own, hand-made lambda:

```
#include <optional>

int heavy_calc() // needed to be called once
{
    // sleep(7500000 years)
    return 42;
}


int main()
{
    struct {
        std::optional<int> cache;
        int operator()() {
            if (!cache) cache = heavy_calc();
            return *cache;
        }
    } foo;
    return foo() + foo();
}
```

It's inlined the same way and you don't need to rely on the capture+mutable hack.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe this is exactly the use case for mutable lambda. If you don't want to have all variables mutable I suggest just creating functor class with one `mutable` field. This way you get best of both worlds (ok, it isn't that concise). The additional benefit is that the `operator()` is `const` (which is quite right, as it always returns same value)

```
#include <optional>

int heavy_calc() {
    // sleep(7500000 years)
    return 42;
}
struct my_functor {
    mutable std::optional<int> cache;
    int operator()() const {
        if (!cache) cache = heavy_calc();
        return *cache;
    }
}

int main() {
    my_functor foo;
    return foo() + foo();
}
```