# Init once with lambda function pointer, self-modifying (C++)

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, c++17

I was wondering if it's possible to create inline lambda initialization function, so after initialization it would replace itself with dummy initialization. Some sort of lazy initialization algorithm with as less pain as possible. Here is some pseudo code what I would like to achieve:

```
SomeData* data = nullptr;
auto initF = [&]
{
    data = initData();
    initF = [&] {};
};
```

so in for loop it would look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     initF();
     data[i] = ....;
}
```

Basically if count is 0 - initF would not be ever called, but once called - pointer becomes initialized and can be used after that.

Comment: This may be a question based on an over-simplified example, but why not do the initialization outside of the loop?

Comment: Maybe related (disclaimer, my question): [Clean way to lazy initialize and cache internal value in lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251340/clean-way-to-lazy-initialize-and-cache-internal-value-in-lambda)

Comment: Initialization outside of for loop is performed always, I would like to avoid initialization when not needed. This of course could have penalties in for loop performance, it would be good to document that in answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code almost works. Since `initF` essentially has to change types, from something that actually does work to just a no-op, you can use a `std::function`:

```
int data;
std::function<void()> calcData = [&]() {
    data = 5; // something expensive
    calcData = []() { }
};
```

I think you can go further and just eliminate `data`'s separate existence, so you just have the function.

```
std::function<int&()> data = [&]() -> int& {
    return (data = [res = 5]() mutable -> int& { return res; })();
    //              ^^^ the variable becomes a "hidden" data member of the closure
}
```

This eliminates the chance of accidentally using the variable before you call the initializer.

Answer (score -1):

Use a [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

```
std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(void)>> initf;
```

Then use [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) to initialize it (with some [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)), or some static constructor initializing it, e.g.

```
//untested
initf.reset (& [&] () { initf = [&]() {
   auto oldinitf=initf; static int cnt;
   cnt++;
   std::cout << "cnt=" << cnt << std::endl;
   if (oldinitf)
      (oldinitf.get()) ();
});
```

Read also about the Y [fix-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) in the untyped  [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).

Queinnec's book *Lisp in Small Pieces* (and [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)) is related to your question.

Observe that [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) in memory require an indirection at least (so are unfriendly to [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) approaches).

On Linux you could generate some similar C++ code at runtime (using raw function pointers), compile it into a temporary plugin, and then use `dlopen` with `dlsym` (I did that several years ago in [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/), now obsolete). See [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/) and look into [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) as an example (of a C++ program generating then running C++ code). Look also into [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit), etc...

Observe that such tricks are easier with [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/), once you made the efforts of learning [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp). SBCL is generating machine code at most [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interactions.

Comment: What is added value of `std::shared_ptr` here? Wouldn't just `std::function` object be enough?

Comment: Or even `std::call_once` on lambda itself?

Comment: There is a circularity. How would you handle it? Feel free to provide a better answer

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but currently your answer is bunch of high-level ideas and links which make sense only if you already know the answer (I don't). I don't intent to attack your approach, but I am trying to understand why `shared_ptr` is needed on top of `function` if `function` can be reinitialized. About circular references: I always believed that `shared_ptr` can introduce them and only wise use of `weak_ptr` can break them. Since you give no code example it is hard to guess your idea.

Comment: I did improve my answer